# Lagom -LagomServiceLocatorStart :Failed to start embedded Service Locator or Service Gateway?

Tags: scala, akka, lagom

I have just started with lagom , was trying to run the lagom example, but i am facing an error in starting the server its self. I am having the following error

```
     > runAll
     [info] Starting Kafka
     [info] Starting Cassandra
     ....Kafka Server closed unexpectedly.
     ......
     [info] Cassandra server running at 127.0.0.1:4000
    [error] p.c.s.NettyServer - Failed to listen for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:8000!
    [error] ({.}/*:lagomServiceLocatorStart) Failed to start embedded               

    Service Locator or Service Gateway. Hint: Are ports 8000 and 9010     
    already in use?
    [error] Total time: 32 s, completed Jan 28, 2017 1:19:03 AM
```

I have changed three parameter in build.sbt still no change

```
     lagomServiceGatewayPort in ThisBuild := 9010
     lagomServiceLocatorStart in ThisBuild := 9005
     lagomServicesPortRange in ThisBuild := PortRange(40000, 45000)
```

any ideas , what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: When i was going through the documentation , it was written , usually it doesn't happens , because the port range is high , but then why is not able to start .

Comment: Did you run `reload` in sbt after changing the configuration?

Comment: yes i have reloaded it and also build it again

Answer (score 1):

You should change the port with the `lagomServiceLocatorPort` setting instead of `lagomServiceLocatorStart`

```
lagomServiceLocatorPort in ThisBuild := 9005
```

See http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/java/ServiceLocator.html#default-port

Answer (score 0):

**Using jdk-8 worked for me**

Did not worked for any of higher versions, must be some compatibility issue to debug more

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).